# Cannot apply a transparent background to the a child div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html design:

```css
body
{
  background-color: green;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #e3eaef;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-header, .card-title {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.card-header {
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3eaef;
}

.card-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-4 {
    padding: 2.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header pt-4 pb-4 text-center bg-primary">
        <span>THIS IS THE HEADER</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body p-4">
    THIS IS THE BODY
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Login </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is how the author of the `theme` has created the `cards`. Now, I want make the `header` of the `card` transparent, so I can see the color of the background.

I tried to apply `background-color: transparent;` to `card-header` class, and of course this won't work because the class `card` have a white color, but I cannot modify the class `card` because I'll lost the color for the body controls.

[This is a test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzSG8/2375/) ready for you.

And this is actually the result:

[image]

Essentially the `header` should have as `background` the green color.

Comment: *Essentially the header should have as background the green color.* Then set that as a background-color.

Comment: @connexo I can't because I'm using `particle.js` which have animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the `background-color: #fff;` on the `.card` element if you want the `.card-header` to view the background color of the body. You can move that white background color to other elements within the card instead, but fundamentally it is not possible to have the "stacking" order be:

```
.card-header -> .card -> body
```

Where `.card` has a solid background, yet `.card-header` is supposed to "see through that" and view the background of the `body`.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #e3eaef;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}


/* All immediate children of card (that aren't the header) will have a white bg */

.card > *:not(.card-header) {
  background-color: white;
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-header,
.card-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card-header {
  padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3eaef;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card-body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-4 {
  padding: 2.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header pt-4 pb-4 text-center bg-primary">
    <span>THIS IS THE HEADER</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body p-4">
    THIS IS THE BODY
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Login </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If, I am understanding your question correctly, it seems like you want to change the background color of your header.

To do this, you can change the opacity of the background color if you chose to in the .card css:

```
.card {
background-color: #ffffff00; }
```

Which will make the opacity of the card transparent. You can also make it semi transparent, by changing the last two digits to any number between fa and 00, like #ffffff7a. Alternatively you can just put the word transparent here as well.

```
.card {
background-color: transparent; }
```